# SQL Server Analysis Services Error (Data mining)

Tags: ssas

Dear I write this DMX query :

```
Select flattened PREDICTHISTOGRAM(disease) 
From patient_examination
NATURAL PREDICTION JOIN
(Select 
52 as patient_age
,1 as chest_pain_type_id
,112 as rest_blood_pressure
,0 as blood_sugar
,3 as rest_electro_type_id
,96 as max_heart_rate
,1 as exercice_angina
) as t
```

but this error happened:

> Executing the query ... Error (Data mining): Either the user, 'Server
>   Name', does not have permission to access the referenced mining model
>   or structure, 'patient_examination', or the object does not exist. Run
>   complete

Comment: Is 'Server Name' the right user?

Comment: Can you tell me about the correct role and Permission